# query about mobile game in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile

I am a game developer and I am developing a 3D mobile game in Unity 3D. Can I use a fixed update while developing the game? When I am using fixedUpdate my game is not working in mobile and without fixedUpdate also it is not working so how can I use fixedUpdate with mobile game.

Comment: If it's not working with or without FixedUpdate something else is likely wrong

Comment: Can you share the code that isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you're facing issues using FixedUpdate in your Unity 3D mobile game. Here's how I can help:

1. Analyze the code:

Sharing the code that's not working would be incredibly helpful. This allows me to analyze what's causing the problem with and without FixedUpdate.
Look for any errors or warnings in the console when running the game with and without FixedUpdate.
Are you manipulating the transform directly within FixedUpdate? This is a common mistake that can lead to unexpected behavior.
2. Understand FixedUpdate:

FixedUpdate runs at a fixed interval regardless of the frame rate, which is crucial for physics and animation. However, it's not always necessary for all game mechanics.
If you're not using physics or animation directly in FixedUpdate, it might be causing issues on mobile devices due to their limited processing power.
3. Alternative approaches:

Consider using Update instead of FixedUpdate for handling game logic, user input, and other non-physics-related tasks.
You can use Time.deltaTime to adjust your calculations based on the actual frame rate.
If you need precise timing for some elements, consider using Coroutines or ScheduledActions.
4. Additional resources:

Unity's documentation on FixedUpdate: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/update-and-fixedupdate
A forum thread discussing FixedUpdate and mobile games: https://forum.unity.com/threads/mobile-movement-with-update-or-fixedupdate.1237165/
Remember, the key is to understand why your game isn't working and then choose the right approach based on the specific needs of your game mechanics.

Feel free to share the code you're struggling with or any additional information about your game, and I'll be happy to help you further!